# php generated URL link

Tags: 7, routes

I have a menu link that is a link to another client site. This uses a single-sign-on. The users info(in Drupal) is sent via SOAP to create a URL with a authenticated ticket for them to use to login. The ticket is a one use ticket. I can't figure out where to implement this,  I feel like this is something that needs to be done between jquery and hook_menu maybe? The problem is that this SOAP code needs to be called every time a user clicks this link.

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm using drupal 7.

thanks
-fw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure jQuery is really necessary here.

If I've understood you right you could have your link pointing to a path with a menu callback which requests your token via SOAP, and then simply forwards the user on to a URL containing that token as a parameter

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['goto-other-site'] = array(
    'title' => 'Forwarder',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_forwarder',
    'access arguments' => array('some permission')
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_forwarder() {
  $token = MYMODULE_function_to_generate_token();

  if (!$token) {
    return 'An error occurred.';
  }

  // Add a query string containing the token.
  $options = array(
    'query' => array(
      'auth_token' => $token
    )
  );

  $url = 'http://other-site.com/';
  drupal_goto($url, $options);
}
```

Apologies if I've got the wrong end of the stick here.

**UPDATE**

Just a bit more to address your comments:

You can use [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to place each link in a specific menu in the system by using the `menu_name` key like so:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['goto-other-site'] = array(
    'title' => 'Forwarder',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_forwarder',
    'access arguments' => array('some permission'),
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'weight' => -10
  );

  return $items;
}
```

The `weight` key describes where in relation to other menu items this link should sit in the menu (a lower number means earlier in the list). When you add a menu link in this manner it will be automatically added to the correct menu so you don't need to add a custom link through the UI (you can delete the one you've already made).

Have a quick read of the [Module developers guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) to get familiar with that side of things, in this case you're only going to need a `.info` and `.module` file.

Hope that helps

Comment: I think this is right. I'm still trying to understand the mechanics of drupal, i get confused real easy. The question I have now is do I make an actual module? This link is coming from the menu module, can I override that module? do I hack the existing?

Comment: When say the link is coming from the menu module do you mean you've added it through the menu UI or that it's an internal path provided by the menu module itself (e.g. one of the menu admin pages)?

Comment: to clarify, I'm using a **main-menu** from the menu admin to consruct the link for this. So I guess I need to know where this goes and what the method is named? MODULENAME_main_menu_menu? main_menu_menu? This is the stuff I just never get. thanks.

Comment: Drupal hooks go on the convention: MODULENAME_hook_name(), so if your module is called `test` when you implement `hook_menu()` the function name will be `test_menu()`. When you use `hook_menu` you can actually specify what real menu in the system you want to add the link to (e.g. main menu). I'll update the answer with a bit more info